# Am I passing a reference to the same subTile (object) or does the array have a separate subTile (Object)?

Tags: c#

For starters, this is working. I am able to access each separate subTile. But my understanding of passing references into arrays make me question what is going on here.

This is using C# with Visual Studio and Unity.

subTile is a struct

```
public void SetSubtilesCenters() {
    SubTile subTile = new SubTile();

    for (int i = 0; i < subTiles.Length; i++) {
        subTile.center = this.transform.position + VerticiesManager.subtileCenters[i];

        SetSingleSubtile(subTile, i); //subtile being added to the array, is this a new subtile each time or is it the same one over and over?
    }
}

private void SetSingleSubtile(SubTile subTile, int index) {

    subTiles[index] = subTile; 
}
```

Comment: This depends entirely on whether `SubTile` is a `class` or a `struct`

Comment: @UnholySheep - To clarify - the `subTile` in the `for` loop is the same every time regardless if it is a `class` or a `struct`, but the one assigned to the array is different if `SubTile` is a `struct`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Subtile is a struct.

Comment: Since it is a `struct`, a COPY is made when you pass it to `SetSingleSubtile()`.  See [How to know the difference between passing a struct and passing a class reference to a method (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-know-the-difference-passing-a-struct-and-passing-a-class-to-a-method).

Comment: @BrandonSteele - An a copy is made when `subTile` is assigned to the array. Lots of copying happens here.